# Fill the missing values (NA) in various columns (independently of each other) using imputeTS package (in particular, na_kalman function)

Tags: r, missing-data

A friend of mine has recently started working on R-studio and is interested in filling the NA values in different columns using the above-mentioned function. Also, since he intends to run a time series analysis for every column, what should be the correct approach?

Comment: I think, the initial decision should be to consider:

`1.` Is imputation the right thing to do? Sometimes, replacing the missing values does not make sense.

`2.` If imputation is the right choice, what exactly do you want to achieve: `a)` replace by column mean, `b)` replace by row mean `c)` or replace by the mean of a given user based on other responses they have

Comment: I want to replace by the column mean.

Answer (score 0):

To replace by column means, an easy approach would be to use the base R function `colMeans`. Let's say you have a data frame `df`.

1) If you want to replace the NAs per column one by one, you could try this:

```
df <- sapply(df, function(x)ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), x))
```

2) If you want to replace all NAs in one go, you could try this:

```
df <- ifelse(is.na(df), rep(colMeans(df, na.rm=TRUE), rep(nrow(df), ncol(df))), unlist(df))
```